# how do I get all my fork(ing) children to execute at the same time?

Tags: perl, fork

I have a process where I want the main thread to run through a loop and produce n number of children, all of which should sleep for j seconds and then (more or less) simultaneously wake up and do their thing.

My code looks like this [Edited as per Dre's request]:

```
 #THE IDEA HERE IS SOMETIMES I WANT TO HOLD THE 
SMS DELIVERY FOR $smsDelay number of seconds 
    if($smsDelay){
            my $forkPid = fork();
            if($forkPid){
                next;
            }
            elsif($forkPid == 0){
                                #db connection disappears while children wait, so, need to reconnect (probably not the best way to handle THIS either! :)
                $myDbC = DBI->connect([DBLOGIN STUFF]) or myDie("can not connect to db");
                &logData("WAITING $smsDelay SECONDS TO SEND SMS");
                sleep($smsDelay * 1);
                $t = time();
                print "sending SMS";
                &send_sms_message($userPN, $smsText , $smsCampaignId);
                print "SMS sent";       
                my $smsVerification = &getDeliveryStatus($userPN, '.smslog');       
                &logData("SMS delivery for $userPN, filename:$filename. Status = $smsVerification");
                #save mms, sms, response code in db
                &runSQL([SQL HERE]);
                exit; #this should only exit the fork, not the entire process!
            }
        }else{
            #HERE I WOULD SEND SMS IMMEDIATELY WITHOUT DELAY

        }
```

What I'm seeing is that each child is executed in succession, but each one waits j seconds IN BETWEEN the next! This is not what I'm after (and frankly totally confusing).  What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: can you please post your actual code, and not what your code looks like -- there is likely a subtle mistake somewhere that you missed when telling us what your code looked like.

Comment: Additionally, can you check if fork is returning undef ( that is before `if($pid == 0)` add sometthing like `die "fork failed" if $pid == undef;`

Comment: no, it's 0... I must be doing something else wrong...

Comment: By thre way, reconnecting to the DB in the child process is a good thing. Sharing the same connection as the parent is not likely to work.

Comment: Do the "WAITING..." messages all show up at the same-ish time, or is there a delay between each.  From this section, all I can guess is that your DBI->connect blocks while another child is using it. If that's not the case, do you have something like `$smsDelay = $smsDelay + $something;` inside the loop that this code snippet is in?

Comment: I don't, but I just removed the code that updates the DB and sends the SMS and now they do all fire at about the same time, so, something in those calls must be forcing the time distribution. At least I'm glad that the DB reconnection is not a terrible idea :) I'll keep plugging away to see what's causing the delay, sorry to waste everyone's time :(

Comment: @Dre, `$pid == undef` is a broken test.  You meant `not defined $pid`.

Comment: @cjm yeah, sorry, I really should not SO when Im tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should simultaneously wake up, and they do when I tested. My code:

```
print "parent: ".localtime."\n";
for (1..3) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid == 0){
       sleep(3);
       print "$$: ".localtime."\n";
       exit(0);
    }
}

1 while wait != -1;
```

Unix:

```
parent: Wed Mar  9 22:21:27 2011
29757: Wed Mar  9 22:21:30 2011
29755: Wed Mar  9 22:21:30 2011
29756: Wed Mar  9 22:21:30 2011
```

Windows (fork emulation):

```
parent: Thu Mar 10 01:19:39 2011
-3836: Thu Mar 10 01:19:42 2011
-4600: Thu Mar 10 01:19:42 2011
-4400: Thu Mar 10 01:19:42 2011
```

I suspect the problem is in the code you didn't show.

Comment: when I exit(0); rather than just exit; my MAIN thread loses it's DB connection... I'm unclear on what the distinction is.  When I exit; then the main thread keeps its DB connection, but the child threads sleep in succession, rather than get loaded all at once and wake up all at once.

Comment: The problem is that you have multiple copies of some database handle variable, one in the parent and one in each child. When the child exits, the variable's destructor is called and it closes the database connection for everyone using it (i.e. the parent). POSIX's _exit will exit the process without calling destructors or calling END blocks.

Comment: The best solution is to not connect to the database in the parent at all.

Comment: unfortunately, the parent has to do most of the DB work in this program. The messaging is a last bit in a long line of processing, and until tonight (where my client suddenly requested a time delay before the messages get sent) everything worked brilliantly. :)

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to exec a fresh perl in the children, and communicate whatever they need via the command line or via a pipe.

Comment: Simplest save for _exit which is arather "dirty" solution.